# Checkbox lost checked value when scroll my custom ListView

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

**What I have:** a custom listview with Textviews and checkbox.
**Problem:** if I check the initial items that are shows on the screen and then I scroll the list, when I return to the top of the list (scroll up) their value is correctly saved. But if I scroll the list and for example I want to check the last tree checkboxs of my list then if I scroll up and down they become unchecked....WHY?**

I have seen various solution for the same problem in other forums and also here on stackoverflow, but the problem persists.
Below my getView function that I think is ok:

```
    @Override
      public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_select_friends, null);
        viewHolder=new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.nameText=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.personName);
        viewHolder.surnameText=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.personSurname);
        viewHolder.contactImage=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.personImage);
        viewHolder.checkBox=(CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

        viewHolder.nameText.setTag(viewHolder.nameText);
        viewHolder.nameText.setTag(viewHolder.surnameText);
        viewHolder.contactImage.setTag(data[position]);
        viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(data[position].isCheck());  
        viewHolder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  

            public void onClick(View arg0) {  

                if(viewHolder.checkBox.isChecked()==true)   
                    data[position].setCheck(true);  
                else  
                    data[position].setCheck(false);  
            }  
        });
    }
    else{
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.nameText.setText(data[position].getName());
    viewHolder.surnameText.setText(data[position].getSurname());
    viewHolder.contactImage.setImageResource(data[position].getPhotoRes());
    viewHolder.contactImage.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(data[position].isCheck());
    return convertView;
}
```

**SOLVED**: I solved my problem of getView whit this code:

```
    public class NewQAAdapterSelectFriends extends BaseAdapter {
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private Person[] data;
boolean[] checkBoxState;
ViewHolder viewHolder;

public NewQAAdapterSelectFriends(Context context) { 
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}


public void setData(Person[] data) {
    this.data = data;
    checkBoxState=new boolean[data.length];
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return data.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int item) {
    return data[item];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}



@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_select_friends, null);
        viewHolder=new ViewHolder();

        viewHolder.nameText=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.personName);
        viewHolder.surnameText=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.personSurname);
        viewHolder.contactImage=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.personImage);
        viewHolder.checkBox=(CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    }
    else{
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.nameText.setText(data[position].getName());
    viewHolder.surnameText.setText(data[position].getSurname());
    viewHolder.contactImage.setImageResource(data[position].getPhotoRes());
    viewHolder.contactImage.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(checkBoxState[position]);
    viewHolder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

           public void onClick(View v) {
               if(((CheckBox)v).isChecked()){
                   checkBoxState[position]=true;
                   data[position].setCheck(true);
               }else{
                   checkBoxState[position]=false;
                   data[position].setCheck(false);
               }
            }
        });
    return convertView;
}


static class ViewHolder {
    TextView nameText;
    TextView surnameText;
    ImageView contactImage;
    CheckBox checkBox;
}
```

}

I have seen this tutorial to do my getView: http://androidcocktail.blogspot.it/2012/04/adding-checkboxes-to-custom-listview-in.html

Answer (score 2):

When you use `new` to create a class even in method, you have created a different scope for your variables.  In other words:

```
// Creating a new scope here -->       vvv
viewHolder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    // Any variables not visible to the entire class, won't work properly in here! 
    //  (variables like: viewHolder, position, possibly data) 
    public void onClick(View arg0) {  
        if(viewHolder.checkBox.isChecked()==true)   
            data[position].setCheck(true);  
        else  
            data[position].setCheck(false);  
    }  
}); // Exited "new class'" scope
```

`position` is not the same `position` that you think it is. Try saving the value of `position` where you can reference it again:

```
viewHolder.checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
viewHolder.position = position;
convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
...

viewHolder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
    public void onClick(View view) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        data[viewHolder.position].setCheck(viewHolder.checkBox.isChecked());   
    }  
});
```

Since you are dealing with a CheckBox though I would recommend using an [OnCheckedChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener.html).

But you may not need to define any listeners for the ListView rows if you change the [ChoiceMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setChoiceMode%28int%29):

```
listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
```

Comment: Hi, thank for the answer. I changed my code like you suggest, but now when i click on a checkbox i have a NullPointerException on the line     data[viewHolder.position].setCheck(viewHolder.checkBox.isChecked());  Why???

Comment: Use your debugger or logcat statements to confirm that `viewHolder` is not null, has a `position`, has a CheckBox and that data[viewHolder.position] is valid as well. But I think I see where I goofed, try this: `ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) ((View) view.getParent()).getTag();;`

Comment: Sam, i change my code again as you sugget,but using Log.i(String,String) i have seen that when i click on a checkbox the viewHolder.position is right(my dislapy can show 8 items at time, so viewHolder.position have a range in 0,1,2,3..7 and the next element restart as 0,1,..(for the recycling). With log i check that data[viewHolder.position].getNamePerson() is also correctly for each element. The firts 8 elements (0,1,2..7) at top of the list works (their checkbox status is saved when i scroll). The problem persists for the next elements after the first 8, who don't maintain their value never.

Comment: And for example, if i check only the last element of the list(the element that is showed with index 7), when i scroll up to the top of the list i have this result: 1) the element that i checked (the last of the list) return unchecked, and the element at top of the list that now is show at index 7 is checked!!!! So it seems that the onclick on the other element(after the first 8 of the list) change the value of the first 8. So if i scroll the fifth element at the end of list,the the fifth element at top of the list is checked and so on...Please helpe Me!!!

Comment: Sorry i mean, ....So if i check the fifth element at the end of list,the the fifth element at top of the list is checked and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Also add `viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(checkBoxState[position]);` after `viewHolder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangedListener` or `viewHolder.checkBox.setOnClickListener`.

Because after scroll, when listview recycle it's view, it will use `setChecked` on the basis of old listeners which may in certain case loose values.

so here is the flow -

```
getView()
---
---
---
viewHolder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangedListener()
---
---
---
viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder>
{
    boolean[] checkBoxState;


    public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> list ) {
        checkBoxState = new boolean[list.size()];
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder( final ViewHolder holder,  final int position) {
        holder.checkBox.setTag(position); 

            holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                    if(compoundButton.isPressed()) // check whether user pressed the checkbox.
                    {
                        int getPosition = (Integer) compoundButton.getTag();  // Here we get the position that we have set for the checkbox using setTag.
                        checkBoxState[getPosition] = compoundButton.isChecked(); // Set the value of checkbox to maintain its state.
                    }
                }
            });

            holder.checkBox.setChecked(checkBoxState[position]);
    }   

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {
        public CheckBox checkBox;
        public ViewHolder(View v,MainActivity mainActivity) {
            super(v);
            checkBox= (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }
}
```

When scrolling, onCheckedChanged() method may be invoked automatically. So, you  may need isPressed() method to check whether the user pressed the checkbox. My adapter class is shown as above. Note that when you add new elements to your list, you should update your boolean array checkBoxState, for example when you add an element to the list you should call the following :

```
checkBoxState = new boolean[list.size()+1];
```

or use an arraylist to hold boolean variables and add element to this arraylist, whatever you want.

I also implement a project for this solution. You can download it from here :
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ssm58w62gw32i29/recyclerView_checkbox_highlight.zip?dl=0

Screenshots are below :

[image: screen1]
[image: screen2]
[image: screen3]
[image: screen4]

Comment: the question is about `ListView`class, not `RecyclerView`

Comment: The same problem also occurs in the recyclerView. The same solution may be carried out for the listView by implementing a custom adapter class for listView.